# Connecting to a table in a database at run-time, and pulling data out?

Tags: .net-core, ado.net, entity-framework-core, database-connection

At the moment i have a db context for storing all information about users that i will need, and now i am wanting to allow the user to specify a connection to a db at runtime (e.g. front-end).

With this connection i want to achieve the below:

- Find all tables in db
- Grab data from a table into by back-end to pass it through to my front-end ( i will use pagination)
- I want to provide filtering for this table on the front end, so i am going to have to know the types of the columns?

My question is what can i use to provide this functionality, I don't think EF core particular meets my needs for this situation. Could i possibly use ADO.net running SQL statements to get schema's etc. and then process this in my back-end? or is there a more known technology i can use?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use TSQL or a Sproc to pull that type of information.

1. To find all tables

```
select * from sys.tables
```

2. To find column types

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'db_MYTABLENAME'
```

You can then process this on your backend

To Use EFCore you can use an sproc like this

```
        public virtual List<sproc_TableData_Result> sproc_TableData(string tablename)
        {
            var TableParameter = new SqlParameter("table_name", tablename);

            var qry = new RawSqlString(@"EXEC sproc_TableData @tablename);

            return Set<sproc_TableData_Result>().FromSql(qry, TableParameter).ToList();
        }
```

This will allow you to get objects back which you can process

Comment: How can you create that sproc_TableData_Result object? as i do not know the structure of the table until i have read it in.

Comment: you will have to run the sql in sql management studio and look at the result. Then create an object that matches that result

Comment: I think you are missing the point, i do not have access to the tables, they are defined at run time, so i have to dynamically create these objects based on table schemas. I am using data tables atm which is pretty clean!

Comment: Yes, the 2 queries above will give you the metadata on the tables - irrespective if they are only known at runtime. You use this metadata to then deal with the table - however all queries to these tables will have to be dynamic TSql

Comment: I decided to read the table into a data-table and then just pass that through to my front end, this way i have it in a structured manner and i can pass it where ever i want :), thanks.